# std::promise<T> where T must be default constructible in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following code in Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::promise<std::reference_wrapper<int>> promise;
    (void)promise;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> error C2512: 'std::reference_wrapper': no appropriate default constructor available

Whereas it compiles fine with GCC and Clang.

Is this is a definite bug in Visual Studio or is it a valid implementation of std::promise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60897/c-shared-state-futuresstate-default-constructs-the.html) in MSVC's standard library implementation.
A simpler reproduction scenario:

```
#include <future>
struct NoDefaultCtor
{
    NoDefaultCtor() = delete;
};
int main() {
    std::promise<NoDefaultCtor> p;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you do not need `std::reference_wrapper<int>`. There is the suitable overloaded template for `std::promise` available:

```
template<class R> class promise<R&>;
```

Therefore you can fix your code in Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::promise<int&> promise;
    (void)promise;
}
```

Comment: This may be a valid workaround for some cases but doesn't address the actual question about T having to be default constructible.