# Why MSVC C++ requires a default constructor in struct needed when returning from async?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following code complains `error C2512: 'MyStruct': no appropriate default constructor available` when trying to compile with MSVC. It works fine with `clang`

```
struct MyStruct{
    int val;
    explicit MyStruct(int v): val(v){}
};

int main()
{
    auto ret = std::async([](){MyStruct ms{50}; return ms;});
    std::cout << ret.get().val;

    return 0;
}
```

Where does it require  in this code to invoke the default constructor?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689319/error-c2512-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

Comment: Maybe because MSVC is a buggy compiler? :)

Comment: I would speculate that MSVC's implementation of `std::future` maybe has a `T`/`MyStruct` member. Anyways, probably a MSVC bug

Comment: MyStruct ms{50}; - I think this invokes it. Why you use { } instead of ( ) ?

Comment: @Alex `{...}` is uniform initialization introduced in C++11

Comment: This is not a problem with `MyStruct ms{50}`. It is the problem with returning ms and moving it into a **defualt constructed** resulting value holder.

Comment: Hi, hope you don't mind that I marked this as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830864 - I looked into it and both issues have the same underlying cause (std::async uses the std::future/std::promise machinery internally).